# Resize image file_size uploaded via file_field | Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, amazon-s3, paperclip

I don't want to prevent large images from being uploaded. I just want it where when the image is saved to the DB it's saved in a smaller size.

For example if I'm showing the images as `:medium` then I want to resize the images to `:medium` dimensions so that the image will load faster.

```
pry(main)> Inspiration.last
 id: 72,
 user_id: 129,
 name: "",
 image_file_name: "ltc-cover-mon-fri.png",
 image_content_type: "image/png",
 image_file_size: 77198,
 image_updated_at: Sun, 06 Nov 2016 04:20:00 EST -05:00>
```

For example I tried `resize` in the model, but I get `undefined method resize` as an error so I guess `resize` isn't a built-in method.

```
class Inspiration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :small => "150x150>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
  before_save :resize

  def resize
    self.image = self.image.resize "300x300>"
  end
end
```

Comment: You already generated medium style. You can directly use it like- inspiration.image.url(:medirm)

Comment: paperclip will use your named styles sizes and keep the original uploaded with style named `original` >> you can enforce a size to the original saved copy by simply making a style named `original`

Comment: Ahh true @HasmukhRathod. I didn't realize that. I was testing it without `:medium`. Very good. And I guess even if it is saving to the s3 as a larger image there is no harm or foul.

Comment: True @AnthonyGalli.com. In my ongoing project, we are storing images on s3 and it works fine.